# Why isn't Gradle updating the IDEA project correctly when I update the version of a library?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Yet more Gradle build hell which I can't figure out. In our top dependencies we have:

```
  joda_time: [
    'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
  ],
```

And in the project libraries there was:

```
$ find .idea/libraries/*joda_time*
.idea/libraries/Gradle__joda_time_joda_time_2_3.xml
```

So today I try to update it:

```
  joda_time: [
    'joda-time:joda-time:2.9'
  ],
```

And then I run `gradle idea`, which appears to succeed, but if I look in the libraries, it still has the previous version:

```
$ find .idea/libraries/*joda_time*
.idea/libraries/Gradle__joda_time_joda_time_2_3.xml
```

What on earth is it doing? I can even see that it has downloaded and cached the jar file, but the project is still referring to the older version.

**Update:**

It looks like what I'm seeing is that it has added a *new* dependency for the later version. So in the same .iml file for every module, I have a reference to the project library:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="Gradle: joda-time:joda-time:2.3" level="project" />
```

But then I separately have a reference to the jar file directly:

```
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/56498efd17752898cfcc3868c1b6211a07b12b8f/joda-time-2.3.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/5290263bb45387985d253240686ca6fb2bb85b14/joda-time-2.3-javadoc.jar!/" />
    </JAVADOC>
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/ecd8588d8ce0963eb443de31d5fea29e3205f160/joda-time-2.3-sources.jar!/" />
    </SOURCES>
  </library>
</orderEntry>
```

When I change the gradle file to want 2.9, Gradle only updates one of these and doesn't delete the other.

I find this surprising because Gradle is supposed to be the one which "owns" the dependencies. It should, then, be deleting the dependencies from the file and replacing them with its own each time it regenerates the file. Otherwise, every time anyone updates anything, there are going to be problems like this.

So I guess I can see two workarounds at the moment:

1. Try to use module.iml.beforeMerged to clear the contents of the XML before it merges in the new dependencies.
2. Give up on doing it cleanly and make the ideaModule task depend on cleanIdeaModule.

Of course I would still like to know know why it is doing this, so I'll leave the question up.

Comment: Once I saw such a problem, the reason was that it was miltimodule project and the root project didn't apply idea plugin. May be here is something similar

Comment: That is definitely the case. So now I moved the "apply plugin: idea" from subprojects to allprojects. This creates an .iml in the top-level which we don't really want, but doesn't seem to fix the problem either. :/

Comment: Actually applying it to all projects brought back another problem where it renamed one of our .iml files to the wrong name because it was trying to avoid a name collision with one at the root of the project, since the project name and one module name match. So I'm taking that change out for now...